# Strange invalid pickle protocol errors when using Dill

Tags: python-3.x, dill

Recently, Dill has completely stopped working for me. It does this:

```
>>> import dill
>>> dill.dumps([1,2,3])
b'\x80\x03]q\x00(K\x01K\x02K\x03e.'
>>> dill.loads(_)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 260, in loads
    return load(file)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 250, in load
    obj = pik.load()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\pickle.py", line 1039, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\pickle.py", line 1066, in load_proto
    raise ValueError("unsupported pickle protocol: %d" % proto)
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 93
```

The number is different every time. This started happening maybe a month ago; reinstalling Dill with `pip` didn't help.

From stepping through it with a debugger it looks like it's correctly reading in the protocol version from the beginning of the data, then reading one of the first instructions in the pickle data and interpreting it as the protocol version for some reason. I don't really know though, since I don't know much about how `pickle` works.

Comment: Hi I'm the `dill` author.  I don't see this behavior in python `3.5.1` or `3.4.4`, with the latest `dill`.  What's your version of python?  I can see it's `3.4`, but did you update python recently?  Please provide more detail, and potentially log this as a github issue: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues

Comment: Even if I take your pickled string (line 3 above), and do a `loads` on it, I get back `[1,2,3]`.  So, I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns None of my clients are reporting this either; it's definitely just my machine. Updated Python to 3.4.4 a few months before this started. I'm not entirely sure what other system details are relevant.

Comment: There are some debug tools in `dill.detect`, you might try them.  For example, `dill.detect.trace` will trace the pickle `dump` and print out what happens.  I suggest if you are still seeing this behavior, you submit an issue on the `dill` github page -- that way, there's a better format for a detailed discussion with trial and error iterations, feedback, etc.

Comment: Just following up on this... did you either resolve/uncover the issue or submit an issue on github?

Comment: @MikeMcKerns I don't have a GitHub account, and the machine this was happening on had a hard drive failure. Haven't had similar issues on the new machine.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns However, we're actually having a whole 'nother issue with Dill not correctly serializing recursive object trees that we could use some input on: https://gitlab.com/toastengineer/INJECTION/issues/3#note_13270112

Comment: Could you post this somewhere better than tack it on the this unrelated thread?  Either on github (my preference) or on another SO question?